# Where can I find a Hooded Cleanroom Suit in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I've been looking and looking and I can't find one. I have a non-hooded one, but I don't need that! Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the reactor room at the institute. It is the small room before going in the actual room on the desk.

Comment: Thank you so much! You don't know how much I wanted and needed this! I'm forever in your debt! :D